# How to find the global screen position of a Qt app?

Tags: qt

I need the global screen position of a Qt widget for which I need the application's global position. How can this be found?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`widget->mapToGlobal( widget->pos() )`

Answer (score 3):

You want the [pos](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#pos-prop) property of your top-level window:

> This property holds the position of
>   the widget within its parent widget.
>
> If the widget is a window, the
>   position is that of the widget on the
>   desktop, including its frame.

Be sure to also check [this part](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/application-windows.html#window-geometry) of the Qt docs for details.

Comment: The links are broken.

Answer (score 1):

widget->parentWidget().mapToGlobal( widget->pos() )

Answer (score 1):

```
widget->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0))
```